# How to convert string to an associative array in php

Tags: php

I have below string. I need to convert this to an associative array. The string which I am getting, as a result, is coming from ajax and for this format of string I didn't find any solutions.

```
$string= '[{"name":"title","value":"%post_title%"},{"name":"author","value":"%author_name%"}]';
```

I need to convert the above string to an associative array so that I can use that array in foreach.

Comment: That is a JSON String so use `$array = json_decode($string,1);` [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I did not find any solutions given for this format of the string. I found the same question, but the format of the string was different there. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Check the [json.org site](http://json.org/) to familiarize yourself with what JSON looks like. It is used for many things nowadays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with second parameter set to true, in order to convert your input JSON format string to an associative array.

```
$string= '[{"name":"title","value":"%post_title%"},{"name":"author","value":"%author_name%"}]';

// convert the JSON format to array
$output_array = json_decode($string, true);

// print to check output
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output_array); echo "</pre>";
```